# Error when trying to download haskell project template

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to create a new haskell project with visual studio code  using the "simple " template and the template project is not downloaded and i get an error message.

So i run the following command:

```
$ stack new **fs** simple
```

And i get the following response:

```
?[0mDownloading template "simple" to create project "fs" in fs\ ...?[0m
?[0m
?[93mWarning:?[0m Retry number 0 after a total delay of 0 us
         If you see this warning and stack fails to download, but running the command again solves
         the problem, please report here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3510?[0m
?[0m
?[93mWarning:?[0m Retry number 1 after a total delay of 100000 us
         If you see this warning and stack fails to download, but running the command again solves
         the problem, please report here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3510?[0m
?[0m
?[93mWarning:?[0m Retry number 2 after a total delay of 200000 us
         If you see this warning and stack fails to download, but running the command again solves
         the problem, please report here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3510?[0m
?[0m
?[93mWarning:?[0m Retry number 3 after a total delay of 300000 us
         If you see this warning and stack fails to download, but running the command again solves
         the problem, please report here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3510?[0m
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "raw.githubusercontent.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = []
  path                 = "/commercialhaskell/stack-templates/master/simple.hsfiles"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 (ConnectionFailure Network.Socket.sendBuf: does not exist (No such file or directory))
```

Could there be a problem since I am running through company proxy?

Comment: Company proxy would indeed be one of the first things I suspect - I suppose it's also possible stackage was down when you tried this though. In any case, this seems more like a networking issue rather than a programming problem?

Comment: Well i thought that it has to do with the package manager,but thinking about it now it seems it is a networking issue.